# how to fix php post error a 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, html

I want to upload the video URL to my website in my localhost its work but in the server I got a problem
" a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request."
I used to write simple code so you can understand me

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}     
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" >
<input type='text' name="url">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the error message [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNpE.png)
each video embad code have ***script or iframe*** so they are the problem
when I write them I got a problem but if I add something without them like src='------' it will work
edit"

sorry about that I don't mean to upload it I mean to show it using iframe or script that I copied it from the videos upload server
and I tried to change the permission [this is the permission of the file in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdfy4.png)
"

Comment: "its work" ... is it? Because the code you've shown has nothing to do with file uploads. So  we don't really know what you're referring to.

Comment: Start by reading the [PHP Manual section, Handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) give it a go and then ask for help if you cannot get it working

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Anyway a 403 in Apache usually means the account under which Apache runs doesn't have permission to access the file you've mentioned in the URL. So please just check the filesystem permissions.

Comment: "I know that this error from xxs protect"...really? What's XXS? Did you mean XSS? And what makes you say that exactly anyway? Seems like a standard 403 to me.

Comment: sorry about that I don't mean to upload it I mean to show it using <iframe> or <script> that I copied it from the videos upload server

Comment: sorry about my bad question I upload a pic of the file permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it happens because of the server folder permissions. Make sure with upload directory permission.

Comment: can you see the new pic that I add it shows the permission of the file

Comment: I think it may be the file ownership issue.